# 404 1804 error when using Django template and trying to get Javascript located in static folder

Tags: html, django

I am working in a Django template and getting the error 404 1804 when trying to get a javascript script located inside the static folder.

Here is my javascript code, file name is current_time.js, located inside the static folder.

```
const displayTime = document.querySelector(".display-time");
// Time
function showTime() {
    let time = new Date();
    displayTime.innerText = time.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", { hour12: false });
    setTimeout(showTime, 1000);
}

showTime();
```

Here is my Django template

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Personal Page</title> 
</head>
<body>
  <div class= "heading-container">
    <h1> Hi Thien </h1>
  </div>  
  <div class="container">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style_time.css' %}">
    <div class="display-date">
      <h1>{% include 'personal_page_app/datetime.html' with date_time=date_time %}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="display-time"></div>
  <script src="{% static 'current_time.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the error shown in the terminal (only js file, I can still get CSS to work)

```
"GET /static/current_time.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1804
```

Here is my file structure

```
myproject:
    ....
myapp:
    static:
        current_time.js
```

Comment: Can you show the file structure?

Comment: Try adding `STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]` in your settings.py file

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this in your settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = "static/"

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]

# MEDIA_URL = "media/"

# MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "media"
```

Then this in your projects URL file:

```
from django.urls import re_path
from django.views.static import serve
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = (
    [
        # your URLs here
        # re_path(r"^media/(?P<path>.*)$", serve, {"document_root": settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
        re_path(
            r"^static/(?P<path>.*)$", serve, {"document_root": settings.STATIC_ROOT}
        ),
    ]
    # + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
)
```

Then you can simple have your script like this:

```
<script src="/static/current_time.js"></script>
```

If you want the media files, you can uncomment them.

This is the method I use for all of my sites. By using this method, you can deploy your sites without having to perform any additional server configurations for setting up the static and media files. Many people usually set up their sites through their servers - for instance, via ngrok. However, this method does not require that.

Comment: so now do i have to add a subfolder named 'staticfiles' into my static folder? I have updated my file structure into the post. Thanks

Comment: No, you should run python manage.py collectstatic when you change the stuff in the static folder and it automatically creates a staticfiles folder with all the data on static folder.